# asp Repeater ItemTemplate - eval whole object

Tags: asp.net, repeater, asprepeater

Currently I am using asp:Repeater like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="itemsRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <my:Button runat="server" Title='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Title") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

But now, I would like to send whole model to my:Button control like:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="itemsRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <my:TabListButton runat="server" Model='<%# this %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Could you tell me how to handle that?

Comment: Corrected : it should be model

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem... somehow.

Maybe it's the only way to handle that. I know it's not beautiful, but it works:

```
    public ModelType Model
    {
        get
        {
            return this;
        }
    }
```

and then:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="itemsRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <my:Item runat="server" Model='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Model") %>'  />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```